# asp.net dynamic data websites insert of associated tables in the same form

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dynamic-data, scaffolding

Im trying asp.net dynamic data websites. I have a customers table and a customers-telephones table. The dynamic data website creates 2 separated forms for the insert in these tables, and I need my form to have the insert of the customer and the insert of the telephones to be in the same form for requirements of the buyer. is it possible to modify something to have the insert of these 2 tables in the same form and with only one accept button?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a [nested gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), or you can de-normalize your data, giving a fixed maximum of phone numbers per customer.
If you say your customers have maximum 3 different phone numbers (e.g. land, mobile and fax) you can just add these as three new columns on the customers table. In that case you will only need one insert (and one form) to add a customer and all his/her phone numbers.

Comment: thanks. I just gave an oversimplified example so denormalizing wont fly, but im taking a look to the nested gridview idea now.

Comment: @Pablo [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EditNestedDataGrid.aspx)'s also editable.

Comment: I was told by a Microsoft MVP that he's going to show in his blog how to do it in a few weeks